IEC 62052-11 Heating test, what does it mean 25 K?
In IEC 62052-11, Heating test, describe as below,

7.2 Heating Under rated operating conditions, electrical circuits and insulation shall not reach a temperature which might adversely affect
the operation of the meter.
The insulation materials shall comply with the appropriate
requirements of IEC 60085.
With each current circuit of the meter carrying rated maximum current
and with each voltage circuit (and with those auxiliary voltage
circuits which are energized for periods of longer duration than their
thermal time constants) carrying 1,15 times the reference voltage,
the temperature rise of the external surface shall not exceed 25 K, with an ambient temperature of 40 °C.

What is 25 K meaning?, What does the K meaning, is it the unit or something else?

C and K are interchangeable unless taking about an absolute scale

Just Googling 'temperature k' would have given the answer, quickly and in great detail. I tried it. Amongst all those results, the Wikipedia article explains it all.

It's kelvin, a temperature unit.
$$
T_K=T_C+273
$$
For temperature rise i.e. \$\Delta T\$, it doesn't matter if you use K (kelvin) or °C (degree Celsius) because it's going to be equal for both.
So a temperature rise of 25 K still means a temperature rise of 25 °C.
